# How to use JsonLoader in pig to load data

Tags: json, apache-pig, elephantbird

Suppose I have a json file in this form:

```
    {"kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable", "rows": [["2015-03-23", "a1jkKOrbYuQ", 141],["2015-03-24", "a1jkKOrbYuQ", 14]]}
    {"kind": "youtubeAnalytics#resultTable", "rows": [["2014-03-23", "a1jkKzubYuQ", 141],["2014-03-24", "a1jkKzubYuQ", 14]]}
```

Follwing is the pig script I wrote which simply allows loading and dumping a file:

```
    A = LOAD '/user/hdfs/youtube_data_views_' using JsonLoader('kind:chararray, rows:{field:(i1:chararray,i2:chararray,i3:int)}');
    DUMP A;
```

And this is the result I get:

```
    (youtubeAnalytics#resultTable,)
```

Actually, I tried tens of combinations with tuples and bags so that I can make sure that A was properly loaded and not partially. Unfortunately, no one worked. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all what I needed to do was using the elephant bird jar...
Here is the list of jars that you need to Register:

```
    REGISTER 'hdfs://10.1.1.154:8020/user/hdfs/pig_jars/elephant-bird-core-4.4.jar';
    REGISTER 'hdfs://10.1.1.154:8020/user/hdfs/pig_jars/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.4.jar';
    REGISTER 'hdfs://10.1.1.154:8020/user/hdfs/pig_jars/elephant-bird-pig-4.4.jar';
    REGISTER 'hdfs://10.1.1.154:8020/user/hdfs/pig_jars/google-collections-1.0-rc1.jar';
    REGISTER 'hdfs://10.1.1.154:8020/user/hdfs/pig_jars/json-simple-1.1.jar';
```

One last advice: Avoid using the built-in JsonLoader function. You will be waisting your time to get the correct schema...